# How to use Put request using Restful API to create and update same record in the database

Tags: rest

I was asked this question in an interview of late. But I wasn't able to really get my head around how to solve this problem.

The interviewer asked that he wants to use PUT request for both creating and updating a row in the database (totally fine no problem till here). Now the thing is that he wants 2 different clients to send PUT requests to the server, say client (C1) sends a PUT request to create a new row and immediately after that  client (C2) sends a PUT request to update the same row. Now lets assume that C1 sent FirstName:Bob and LastName:Smith when creating a new row in the first place and C2 immediately updated these 2 fields as FirstName:John and LastName:Doe. After all this is done. C1 does a GET request and gets back an unexpected First and Last name. How would you handle this situation so that even after the update is done by C2. C1 still gets the same First and Last Name as Bob Smith rather than John Doe.

Comment: Why would you want stale data? Are you sure you asking the question correctly?

Comment: I didn't get you , what do you mean by staling data?

Comment: Why would you want data that is no longer valid? Isn't the point of having data to have up to date data? That's why I'm wondering if that is even the question being asked.

Comment: I got you, you are right, but that was the conundrum. Because C1 doesn't even know that C2 updated data in the database rather expecting to get the same first and the  last name.

Comment: Here's where I _thought_ you were going with this, when I first started reading: C1 creates data, and has a copy of that data. C2 updates the data. C1 tries to update the data, but has stale data. How do we handle this so that C1 has the up to date data before trying to update?

Comment: That is a more normal use case where the answer would be to use a "conditional PUT" using Etags from the server and If-Match headers on the client. But it doesn't seem like that is your question.

Comment: Also he gave me a little hint that when C1 logs into the system vs. 
when C2 logs in with it's credentials that's how you would first identify them as their credentials would be unique.
 Then I thought whats being done in the database is based on who is logging into the system and what that client can do in the database. 
They might have a table (T1) which is copied over to another table(T2).
 So whenever C1 creates a new row in T1 that will be copied over to T2 and then C2 can update T2 table not T1 and it's all handled with the help of security. Not sure though if I'm right or wrong.

Comment: Ok, may be table partitioning based on userid can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: I still don't understand what the actual problem is. It makes no sense for C1 to `GET` data not current.